# connect Cloud SQL to Data Fusion through sqlproxy with private IP

Tags: mysql, proxy, virtual-machines, google-cloud-platform, vpc-peering

It is my first question in this community I hope that I won't be off-topic. I'm trying to connect data fusion to Cloud SQL for MySQL Instance on Private IP. Here is what I have done so far:

- Creating a private data fusion instance (VPC peering seems to be working fine)
- Creating a Cloud SQL for MySQL instance
- Creating a VM with Proxy SQL installed

I've run multiple connectivity test running the Network Intelligence module and here are the result:

- from Cloud SQL to Proxy SQL => ok
- from Proxy SQL to Cloud SQL => ok
- from cloud data fusion to Proxy SQL => ok
- from Proxy SQL to Cloud data fusion => not ok  (0/50 packets delivered)

I'm not a network engineering. Sorry If I'm making any obvious mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Data Fusion is using a network that needs to allow ingress from the source ip address of the vm instance on which proxy is running. This needs to be changed in firewall policy for that network. The official doc of Cloud Datafusion [1](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/create-private-ip) suggests that protocol and port number should be tcp:22 for this firewall rule.